# meaning of "whereof"

Tags: grammar, lexicon

*I have therefore whereof I may glory through Jesus Christ in those things which pertain to God.* (Romans 15: 17)

I would like to know what *whereof* means in this context. I would also like to know what part of speech it is.

Comment: Have you made any prior attempts to discover this for yourself? The ethos on this website tends to be 'We'll help those who have made an effort and shown signs of the same'.

Comment: I would suggest, particularly if English is not your first language, looking up the verse in a more modern translation. The Authorized Version (i.e. King James Version), while beautiful, was first published in 1611 and contains many archaic words and usages that hinder the modern reader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s a relative pronoun no longer in normal use. One of its meanings was, in the Oxford English Dictionary’s definition, ‘with ellipsis of antecedent as object of a verb = that by which, that with which’. So the first part of the verse means ‘I have therefore that with which I may glory . . .'

Answer (score 2):

> I have therefore whereof I may glory through Jesus Christ in those
>   things which pertain to God.
>
> So I have reasons to thank God for all Jesus Christ has worked through
>   me.

'Have' in both the original and the paraphrase is the main verb (= possess) not the auxiliary.

'Whereof I may glory' is an old-fashioned way of saying 'things I am happy to have done' (in God's service, with Christ's help).

'Whereof' is doubling as a pronoun, as in 'There is **that** that I am pleased to have done . . .'. It's used very rarely nowadays. If you really must investigate this archaic stuff, it's a [compound relative pronoun](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2657189).

Comment: I'd sort out your Modern English first.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to approach the grammar and meaning of works that exist in many languages, versions and editions is to compare them, one to another.  [This](http://www.biblegateway.com/versions/) is a good place to start.